# Prove the existence of order 4 subgroups of order 8 groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am participating in an Introductory course in groups and I have the following question:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $8$. Prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $4$ and a subgroup of order $2$.

i know how to prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $2$ but i can't show the existence of a subgroup of order 4. I am only a begginer in groups so please take this into account.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem ?

Comment: If you are familiar with Sylow theorem, and $p$-groups there is an even more general statement: If $p^k$ divides the order of $G$, where $p$ is prime, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$. In our case we have $2^2$ divides $8$. Of course this exercise is trivial with Sylow, so I am guessing you are not familiar, but it is sometimes nice to be aware of more general results.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is the first thing, you will learn about finite groups. There is almost no chance to solve an exercise in abstract finite group theory without Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is cyclic, that is, if $G=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7\}$, then the elements with even exponents form a subgroup of order $4$.

If not, then take any element $x\neq 1$. If its order is $4$, then we are done (the subgroup would be $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, and if its order is $2$, take any other element $y$.

If the order of $y$ is $4$, then we are done, just like before. If the order of $y$ is $2$, then consider the subset $H=\{1,x,y,xy\}$. If the order of $xy$ is $2$, then $H$ is a subgroup of order $4$. If the order of $xy$ is $4$, it generates a subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: how do i know that there is an element $y\not =1$ of order 2 other than the element $x$ i have already found?

Comment: The order of every element divides the order of the group. This is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: I meant,  why can't all the other elements have order 8?

Comment: There is one thing missing, and that is: One needs to have that $\{1, x,, y , xy\}$ is a subgroup, which seems to me still non-obvious. But it is easily fixable.

Comment: @dorsh605 Well, the unit has always order $1$. And if $x$ has order $8$, then $x^2$ has order $4$.